# In dc.js, why is elasticX not working properly for Time Series Chart

Tags: dc.js

Here is the jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/inasisi/6v639g9g/1/

As you can see the X axis is not scaled properly. I can calculate the min and max date and set the scale properly but don't want to do it after each filter. Would prefer if elasticX works properly.

Any ideas?

```
var chartGroup = "chartGroup";

data = [{
    "run_date": "2013-01-20",
    "current_grade": "Kindergarten",
    "students": 1
}, {
    "run_date": "2013-01-20",
    "current_grade": "First",
    "students": 2
}, {
    "run_date": "2014-03-22",
    "current_grade": "Kindergarten",
    "students": 3
}, {
    "run_date": "2014-03-22",
    "current_grade": "First",
    "students": 4
}, {
    "run_date": "2015-10-06",
    "current_grade": "Kindergarten",
    "students": 5
}, {
    "run_date": "2015-10-06",
    "current_grade": "First",
    "students": 21
}, {
    "run_date": "2015-02-13",
    "current_grade": "Kindergarten",
    "students": 31
}, {
    "run_date": "2015-02-13",
    "current_grade": "First",
    "students": 26
}, ];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.run_date = Date.parse(d.run_date);
});

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

filterDateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return [d.run_date];
});

dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return [d.run_date];
});

var minDate = dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].run_date;
var maxDate = dateDimension.top(1)[0].run_date;

var runsStudentsGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(function (fact) {
    return fact.students;
});

var totalStudentsChart = dc.lineChart("#students_chart", chartGroup);

totalStudentsChart.renderArea(true)
    .width(300)
    .height(300)
    .x(d3.time.scale())
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .dimension(dateDimension)
//.colors('red')
.group(runsStudentsGroup);

dc.renderAll(chartGroup);

$('.day_filter').on('click', function () {
    console.log(dateDimension.top(Infinity));
    console.log($(this).val());

    dateDimension.filter(function (d) {
        console.log(d > new Date(2015, 0, 1));
        return d > new Date(2015, 0, 1);
    });

    console.log(dateDimension.top(Infinity));
    dc.redrawAll();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fix a few things to get the chart to display and to get the filter to work at all.  I'll just quote those without explaining, since those aren't what the question is about:

```
d.run_date = new Date(d.run_date);
//...
return d.run_date; // twice
//...
filterDateDimension.filter(function (d) {
//...
dc.redrawAll(chartGroup);
```

To answer your main question, which is frequently asked, crossfilter does not automatically remove empty bins. You can use a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted) to filter them out.

Adding:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
//...
.group(remove_empty_bins(runsStudentsGroup));
```

Working fork of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8an2n1eL/5/

(The transition in this example is particularly screwy, and [will be fixed in 2.1](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/507).)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That was really helpful.  I would assume that removing empty bins should be the default behavior. Most of the Business Intelligence applications I have used do that.  Any particular reason why you are not doing that?

Comment: This is how crossfilter works - although it will remove groups if you completely [remove the data that created the groups](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/91), it won't if the value just drops to zero. Since there are a [lot of ways you might want to filter the data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted), I think it is better to focus on making it easier to process data coming from crossfilter, rather than [building the functionality into dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/683).